# Xamarin.UITest incompatible with OS X 10.15?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

Today after my iOs upgrade to Catalina 10.15.3 from 10.14.1 I am now getting an os dialog when running Xamarin.UITest

steps to repeat:

1. Create new Xamarin Solution
2. Select Master Detail project
3. Add the UITest project
4. Build all
5. Run templated iOS app in simulator (Verification)
6. open the unit test pad
7. Right Click the first uitest and run
8. Observe the new dialog as pictured in attachment "iOSDeviceManager will damage your computer"

I think this is a new behavior related to MacOSX upgrade. I recall doing this last week without issue.

I am using Visual studio for Mac 8.4

[image]

Comment: trying now. Thank you

Comment: @SushiHangover no luck with that I am all up to date Xcode 11.3 and VS4Mac 8.4.6. Same Exact problem

Comment: I logged on to another computer in hopes it was not OS X 10.15.... Unfortunately it was already upgraded and the steps above led to the same failure. Would some kind person please try simple steps above and report OS X version vsformac version and results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED!  For Some reason I needed to update packages... When I did it just worked. FYI This includes for creating a brand new project from the MasterDetail template. Maybe Xamarin Folks can solve this problem for us somehow. Problem statement: Default Templates for solution create non-running UITests. Workaround update packages fixes problem

Comment: You can mark the answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Which packages did you update? Visual Studio, your project or your system?

Comment: Ok, you mean the Nuget packages. So you should go to the UITest project `> Right click on Packages > Update > Accept the terms when prompted > Rebuild > Run tests again`

Comment: I have all packages updated but reinstalling Xamarin.UITest package solved the problem for me